# Receiving 'Device or resource busy', when calling hid_interrupt_write()

Tags: c, libusb

I am trying to send data to Measurement Computing 1208FS device using libusb and libhid on Xubuntu 12.04. I have successfully identified the device and it's endpoints, and have managed to claim the interface for my program.

When I try to write to an endpoint with hid_interrupt_write() or libusb_interrupt_transfer(), I get an error message "Device or resource busy". This error usually seems to happen when the device is attached to an driver, but I don't think this is a problem in my case, since I have managed to detach the driver.

Here is the code snippet I currently have with 0x83 as the endpoint I'm trying to communicate with:

```
void SendToUSB(int value, HIDInterface* hid)
{
    hid_return ret;
    char packet[] = {value};
    unsigned int timeout = 1000;
    ret = hid_interrupt_write(hid, 0x83,  packet, 1, timeout); 

    if (ret == HID_RET_SUCCESS) printf("SUCCESS calling hid_interrupt_write\n");
    else printf("FAILURE calling hid_interrupt_write(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

I'm fairly new at programming for USB devices, so it is possible I've messed up something very trivial. Any help is appreciated.